# Retrieve private iCal url for a private Calendar using the Java Google Calendar API

Tags: google-calendar-api

I'm trying to access the private url for my private Calendars using the Java Google Calendar API (the one I can see on the UI on the calendar settings
that looks like https://calendar.google.com/calendar/ical/[calendarID]/[magicCookie]/basic.ics).

However, even though I'm authenticated correctly using a service account that I have added as a user to my calendars, when I do

```
service.calendarList().list().execute()
```

I retrieve the calendar and its events but I can't see the private url into the calendar properties (I can retrieve the calendar ID but not the magic cookie).

Is there any way to retrieve this private url programatically using the API?.

Thanks!

Comment: @Cardelco did find a way to retrieve the private url? I am facing the same problem.